# How to export multiple class methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have several methods that return jsx objects that I want to be able to call from outside the class, currently, the only way I found that work is to export arrow functions from outside of the class in the same file, but I end up with too many functions out of the class.

So is there a way to export multiple class methods from the same file and keep them in the class?

I don't want to make a new class for each of those functions because they're related, and I need to call them out of the class so I'll be able to add them in Storybook.

Example of what I want:

```
//A.js 
class A{
  export foo() {return (<div>...</div>)}
  export bar() {...}
}

export default A
```

What I have now that works:

```
//A.js 
export default class A{
...
}
export const foo = () => {...}
export const bar= () => {...}
```

Comment: Might want to use `static` keyword

Comment: But I end up with a file that most of the methods in it are not in the class, isn't that code smell? @ionizer

Comment: Do you mind describing what those functions do?

Comment: They return a jsx object, some of them are pure and some of them call other functions but all of them don't have state.  @ionizer

Comment: If they're not dependent on class variable/properties (with `this`), I think using `static` might be what you really needed. For example, inside your class, use `static foo() {...}`. Otherwise, need to use the common class method.

Comment: @shinzou no it is not a code smell. exporting simple functions is often more clean that exporting complex classes. but it depends on what you are doing

Comment: What's the purpose for such class? Does these methods really use class state? If they don't, you're misusing the class. Classes aren't glorified namespaces. Exporting functions is the proper way here, providing a namespace is is one of purposes of ES modules.

Comment: But honestly using `static` feels like the same as returning a JSON.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your methods does not rely on its own properties or variables (accessed using `this`), you might want to try using `static` methods

```
export default class A {
  static foo() {return (<div>...</div>)}
  static bar() {...}
  ...
}
```

And then, you can use it like so:

```
import A from './A';

A.foo();
```

The advantage of using static method is that you don't need to create an instance to use it. And, it does not get re-created when you create a new instance.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Live Demo:

```js
class A {  
  static foo() {
    return "foo() called";
  }
  
  static bar() {
    console.log(this.foo() + " from bar()");
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    A.bar();
  }
}

new B();
```

Comment: And how do I call another static method from a static method in that class? `this.foo()` doesn't work.

Comment: According to the reference, you can use `this.foo()` from inside `bar()`. Is there any error you encounter using this method? Also, does `class A` happen to `extends React.Component`?

Comment: How do you plan on using this class anyway?

Comment: It doesn't extend `React.Component`. I get an error that it can't find that function. This class is just a view, it has tables, cards, lists, etc.

Comment: That's weird, my example had worked... But is it correct to say that you want to use the JSX from `class A` in another class which extends `React.Component` and render it?

Comment: It's for Storybook (it's like UI unit testing). I'll try to make an online running example later.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to export class methods. Just create an instance of the class and call them:

```
// A.js 
class A{
  foo() {return (<div>...</div>)}
  bar() {...}
}

export default A
```

Import class `A` in other file:

```
import A from './A'

// create instance of class A
const a = new A()

// ... and call your methods on instance `a`
a.foo()
a.bar()
```